# Android App works on emulator, but not on real device

Tags: android, android-emulator, logcat

It works on emulator and real device(android version 4) but it does not working on real device(android version7.0)

**Related Code:**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_action, container);
    application = (LaftelApplication) getActivity().getApplication();
    userId = application.getUserInfo().id;

    ratingBar = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.rating_bar);
    ImageView btnDeleteRating = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete_rating);
    btnSubscribe = (CheckableLinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_subscribe);
    btnWish = (CheckableLinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.wish_item);
    btnRecommend = (CheckableLinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_recommend);
    btnBanRecommend = (CheckableLinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ban_recommend);

    mContext = getContext();
    getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    mItem = (Item) getArguments().getSerializable("item");

    ImageView itemTypeView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_type);
    if (mItem.type.equals(Constants.DB_ITEM_TYPE_ANIMATION)) {
        itemTypeView.setImageResource(R.drawable.label_ani_round);
    } else if (mItem.type.equals(Constants.DB_ITEM_TYPE_WEBTOON)) {
        itemTypeView.setImageResource(R.drawable.label_webtoon_round);
    } else if (mItem.type.equals(Constants.DB_ITEM_TYPE_COMICS)) {
        itemTypeView.setImageResource(R.drawable.label_comics_round);
    } else if (mItem.type.equals(Constants.DB_ITEM_TYPE_LIGHTNOVEL)) {
        itemTypeView.setImageResource(R.drawable.label_lnovel_round);
    }

    TextView itemNameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
    itemNameView.setText(mItem.name);

    // CardAction Setting
    Call<RatingList> userPreferenceCall = application.service.getUserPreference(userId);
    userPreferenceCall.enqueue(new Callback<RatingList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<RatingList> call, Response<RatingList> response) {
            userRating = response.body();
            setUserPreferences();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<RatingList> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });

    Call<SubscriptionList> userSubcriptionCall = application.service.getUserSubcriptionSet("application/json", userId);
    userSubcriptionCall.enqueue(new Callback<SubscriptionList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<SubscriptionList> call, Response<SubscriptionList> response) {
            userSubcriptionInfo = response.body();
            setUserSusbscription();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<SubscriptionList> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
```

**Logcat:**

> 05-23 10:31:39.464 17342-17342/laftel.net.laftel E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: laftel.net.laftel, PID: 17342
>                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int laftel.net.laftel.models.UserInfo.id' on a null object reference
>                                                                          at laftel.net.laftel.views.CardActionFragment.onCreateView(CardActionFragment.java:61)
>                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2192)
>                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
>                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
>                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
>                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
>                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
>                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
>                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
>                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
>                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:710)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6247)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)

Comment: Post your build.gradle file also.

Answer (score 0):

move `application = (LaftelApplication) getActivity().getApplication();` from `onCreateView` to `onActivityCreated`

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    application = (LaftelApplication) getActivity().getApplication();
}
```